# Rock, Paper Scissors game gets me same result when played again

Tags: python

I'm doing a Rock Paper Scissors game in Python. My code is working alright but the one major flaw I'm having trouble with is that when I play again and input the same throw, I keep getting the same message and the message isn't randomized

```
import random

outcomes = ["r", "p", "s"]
compThrow = random.choice(outcomes)

def play():
    throw = input("What is your throw?(r / p / s): ")
    if ((throw ==  "r") and (compThrow == "r")) or ((throw == "p") and (compThrow == "p")) or ((throw == "s") and (compThrow == "s")):
      print("Tie. Try Again"), playAgain()
    elif ((throw == "r") and (compThrow == "s")) or ((throw == "p") and (compThrow == "r")) or ((throw == "s") and (compThrow == "p")):
      print("You Win! Congratulations!"), playAgain()
    elif ((throw == "r") and (compThrow == "p")) or ((throw == "p") and (compThrow == "s")) or ((throw == "s") and (compThrow == "r")):
      print("You Lost. Computer is Victorious"), playAgain()
    else:
      print("Invalid Throw. Please input a proper throw(r/p/s)"), playAgain()
    
def playAgain():
  question = input("Would you like to play again?: ")
  if question == "y":
    return play()
  elif question == "n":
    print("goodbye")
  else:
    print("invalid")

play()
```

And this is what happens

```
What is your throw?(r / p / s): r
You Win! Congratulations!
Would you like to play again?: y
What is your throw?(r / p / s): r
You Win! Congratulations!
Would you like to play again?: y
What is your throw?(r / p / s): r
You Win! Congratulations!
```

What can I do to make sure the result is randomized each time I play again

Comment: You're defining `compThrow` once, at the top of the code, and it never changes.

Comment: Unrelated, but think about how to improve your code with a dict like `beats = {"r": "s", "s": "p", "p": "r"}`

Comment: Please consider [accepting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) if it helped you. This tells others that the problem is resolved and helps others find the correct answer more easily.

Answer (score 1):

Well, what do you expect? :)

**You're determining the computer's choice only once** - at the beginning:

```
compThrow = random.choice(outcomes)
```

And then the value of `compThrow` will stay the same throughout the whole runtime.

If you want the computer's choice to be determined for each play, try putting it inside the `play()` function:

```py
def play():
    compThrow = random.choice(outcomes)
    throw = input("What is your throw?(r / p / s): ")
    ...
```

---

Also, un an unrelated note, as I can't help myself but to nitpick :) ... [PEP8 (Style Guide for Python Code)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) suggests that [you should use `underscore_names` when naming variables and function names](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names). In your case it should be `play_again` rather than `playAgain`, `comp_choice` rather than `compChoice`, etc.

Comment: Camel casing, which is what the OP is doing, is what's recommended for languages like Java and Javascript, not Python.